# My battery was hooked up backwards

Tags: electrical, starting, hyundai

Stupid? Yes, but not my fault, it was dark. 2001 Hyundai Tiburon, are there any fusible links in the starter/ignition system? Now I only get the interior lights, but no engine lights (oil, gas, on, seat belts).  Thank you for your time. That's something I'm running out of.

Comment: Connecting the battery backwards has damaged anything electronic in the car as there is no protection for this mistake, take it to a dealership for an estimate, then you can decide if it is worth repairing. Fusable links have nothing to do with the damage caused by connecting the battery backwards.

Answer (score 1):

On your car, I cannot tell you exactly where the fusable links and fuses are.  There are normally fuses inside the car or in a container under the hood which are labeled for lights, blowers, etc.  Of greater concern is the instrument panel (usually a 5A fuse in that box) and the ECU.  If the electronics on those or any immobilizer are fried then your problem is more severe.

In your instance, I would google the fuse layout for your car, which I easily found in doing so.  Then I would check for the fuses for the instrument panel and the ECU. I would also check the what appears to be  a main fuse (100A). It is also possible that an unfused accessory such as the alternator could have been damaged. Some alternators are connected via fuseable links, and some are not.

You will want a multi meter for testing.

Unfortunately, there is no simple check, and you will have to walk through checking each area for power. Unless you can find someone who has experience with this same problem with this car or a close variant.  I am not that person.

But I can lay out what your starting points would be towards getting your problem diagnosed and resolved.  Ask if you have more questions, and I will refine my answer.

Starter Note: Normally the starters are not fusible linked.  You can test the starter by jumpering the battery to the solenoid, but my guess is that will work. Right now your focus should be on the ignition, instrument and anti-theft systems.  The ECU will be the most important component to get up.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this online service manual](http://www.newtonnet.co.uk/coupe/service/webtech/iindex.asp@id=394881127#_394881127), there are multiple (11) fusible links in the engine compartment fuse box.

[image]

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║   Description   ║ Amperage  ║       Circuit protected        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Fusible link    ║           ║                                ║
║ A (Dark blue)   ║ 100A      ║ Generator                      ║
║ B (Blue)        ║ 20A       ║ Engine control relay           ║
║ C (Pink)        ║ 30A       ║ Power windows                  ║
║ D (Blue)        ║ 20A       ║ A/C condenser fan control      ║
║ E (Red)         ║ 50A       ║ Battery power source           ║
║ F (Green)       ║ 40A       ║ Head lamps, Tail lamps         ║
║ G (Pink)        ║ 30A       ║ Radiator fan control           ║
║ H (Pink)        ║ 30A       ║ ABS control                    ║
║ I (Pink)        ║ 30A       ║ ABS control                    ║
║ J (Pink)        ║ 30A       ║ Ignition power source          ║
║ K (Pink)        ║ 30A       ║ Blower control                 ║
║ Fuse            ║           ║                                ║
║ A/C             ║ 10A       ║ A/C condition control          ║
║ HORN            ║ 10A       ║ Horn                           ║
║ AUDIO           ║ 10A       ║ Audio, TCM, ECM                ║
║ TAIL LAMP (LH)  ║ 10A       ║ Left tail lamps                ║
║ TAIL LAMP (RH)  ║ 10A       ║ Right tail lamps               ║
║ FRONT FOG LAMP  ║ 15A       ║ Front fog lamps                ║
║ H/LAMP (LOW)    ║ 15A       ║ Head lamps                     ║
║ H/LAMP (HIGH)   ║ 15A       ║ Head lamps                     ║
║ Power connector ║           ║                                ║
║ L               ║ -         ║ Fuse 6 (15A), Audio Fuse (10A) ║
║ M               ║ -         ║ Fuse 14 (10A)                  ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```