# Electrical failure

Tags: electrical, battery, starting, alternator, lights

While fitting a new battery for the old one I erred by placing leads in the reverse order, when I corrected my mistake I found when i try to start the car all switch off for a couple of minutes, when I try again the same problem arises. The car is a Mondeo 1.8tdci 2008. Has anyone got any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My battery was hooked up backwards](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/45101/my-battery-was-hooked-up-backwards) That's not the exact same car, so your fuses may differ, but hooking up a battery backwards normally causes some fuses or larger fusible links to blow.  It can take some time to find the right fuse.

Comment: This can damage engine electronics (ecm ect), they might have to be replaced.